# Xcode 4.4 clang error: linker failed

Tags: xcode, linker

After upgrading to Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4 today, one of my projects is no longer compiling. I've verified that it still compiles ok on Xcode 4.3. This is the output I'm getting - any ideas?

```
Ld "/Users/Adam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Home_Loan_Finder-ciynsbeemzwbzhenhqlhhzbsgebo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Home Loan Finder.app/Home Loan Finder" normal i386
    cd "/Users/Adam/Aspyre/Code/Projects/Binary/Home Loan Finder"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/Adam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Home_Loan_Finder-ciynsbeemzwbzhenhqlhhzbsgebo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Adam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Home_Loan_Finder-ciynsbeemzwbzhenhqlhhzbsgebo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-F/Users/Adam/Aspyre/Code/Projects/Binary/Home Loan Finder/../../../SDKs" -filelist "/Users/Adam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Home_Loan_Finder-ciynsbeemzwbzhenhqlhhzbsgebo/Build/Intermediates/Home Loan Finder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Home Loan Finder.build/Objects-normal/i386/Home Loan Finder.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework MessageUI -framework CoreData -framework ShinobiCharts -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -o "/Users/Adam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Home_Loan_Finder-ciynsbeemzwbzhenhqlhhzbsgebo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Home Loan Finder.app/Home Loan Finder"

0  0x103ced280  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x103d43877  ld::tool::OutputFile::addressOf(ld::Internal const&, ld::Fixup const*, ld::Atom const**) + 215
2  0x103d4512c  ld::tool::OutputFile::applyFixUps(ld::Internal&, unsigned long long, ld::Atom const*, unsigned char*) + 300
3  0x103d46a6d  ld::tool::OutputFile::writeAtoms(ld::Internal&, unsigned char*) + 621
4  0x103d42c14  ld::tool::OutputFile::writeOutputFile(ld::Internal&) + 564
5  0x103d3d963  ld::tool::OutputFile::write(ld::Internal&) + 147
6  0x103ced8ef  main + 1263
7  0x103cdc234  start + 52
A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/Home Loan Finder-2012-06-27-140754.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (_mode == modeFinalAddress), function finalAddress, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-133.3/src/ld/ld.hpp, line 657.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: It looks like you found a bug within the linker. Search for a bug-tracker for `clang` and add a bug report there.

Comment: same issue, when I created a category of a class of third party framework (ShinobiCharts)

Comment: Interesting - I am also using ShinobiCharts

Comment: So, turns out removing the ShinobiCharts category fixed the problem for me too. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those, who use ShinobiCharts.framework: creating a category on Shinobi classes causes such error. As a workaround, you can replace categories with inheritance (this may be very painful).

Comment: I found that categories were the problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a look into this at the moment.

We're fairly sure it's because the current frameworks are built using Xcode 4.3 and the 4.4 compiler isn't linking everything together properly.

The solution seems to be simply building the frameworks in Xcode 4.4 - we're reviewing this at the moment and should have updated frameworks out soon!

FULL DISCLOSURE: I work for ShinobiControls on ShinobiCharts.

Edit: A new version of ShinobiCharts is now available, with these issues fixed.

Comment: We're currently testing our next release which fixes this issue (and a couple of other minor things too). Shouldn't be long now.

Comment: @sciasxp If you've bought the component, drop us an email. We've also reset the trial frameworks so that anyone on a trial can download another to continue evaluation :)

Comment: @SimonWithington could you please share any details on how you have fixed the  ShinobiCharts.framework? 
I ran into the same problem with my own iOS library.

Answer (score 0):

To shed some light on this, the fix was to change the "Strip Style" from "All Symbols" to "Non-Global Symbols", allowing the Global Symbols to be used in categories.

Full Disclosure: I also work for ShinobiControls!